# How to create a variable that contains an Operator in Java?

Tags: java, variables, operators, integer-arithmetic

I'm trying to write a program in 30 lines or less for my class (self imposed challenge).

The program asks the user a simple addition, division, multiplication, or subtraction ***question*** and the player answers, rinse and repeat 10 times, then the player is asked if they want to continue or end the program. The type of question (*add*, *mult*, etc.) should be selected randomly.

So that I don't need to use a huge switch case or if-else tree, I want to know if there is any way to contain an operator in a variable, and then use it later.

Example:

```
var operator = +;
int[] n = {1, 2};
System.out.println(n[0] operator n[1]);
```

And the output would be "3"

That's an example of what kinda thing I want to do. Is this possible?

Comment: Just as a side note, doing things in less lines isn't necessarily better a lot of the time.  Sometimes it takes more lines to write something that is easy to read (and practicing readable code and good documentation is important too)

Comment: you can use the `IntBinaryOperator` functional interface for such: `IntBinaryOperator operator = Integer::sum;` (not sure if you already had that in class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's *not possible* to assign an operator to a variable.

> in 30 lines **or less** ... the program asks the user a simple addition, division, multiplication, or subtraction

If you want to implement it using as fewer lines as possible, build-in **functional interfaces** will be a good choice. For that, you need [`IntBinaryOperator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/IntBinaryOperator.html) that represents an operation done on two `int` arguments.

Functional interface can be implemented either by using a [lambda expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) or a [method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) (*also, you can do that with an anonymous inner class as well by it'll not be shorter*). Addition operation can be represented like that:

```
IntBinaryOperator add = Integer::sum; // or (i1, i2) -> i1 + i2
```

> The type of question (add, mult, etc.) should be selected **randomly**

For that, firstly, you need to define a [`Random`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/random/RandomGenerator.html#nextInt(int)) object. In order to obtain a random integer in the given range, use `nextInt()` method that expects an `int` bound, and returns a value from `0` up to the bound (*exclusive*):

```
rand.nextInt(RANGE)
```

To avoid hard-coding, `RANGE` should be defined as a global constant.

Because your application has to interact with the user, every *operation* should be associated with a *name* that will be exposed to the user.

It can be done by declaring a [`record`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/language/records.html) (*a special kind class with* `final` *field and auto-generated constructor, getters*, `hashCode/equals`, `toString()`). Syntax for declaring records is very concise:

```
public record Operation(String name, IntBinaryOperator operation) {}
```

*Records* representing arithmetical operations can be stored in a *list*. And you can pick an operation by generating a random index (from `0` up to list size).

```
operations.get(rand.nextInt(operations.size()))
```

Unlike the common getters, names of getters that will be generated by the compiler for the record will identical to names of its fields, i.e. `name()` and `operation()`.

In order to use the function retrieved from the record, you need to invoke the method `applyAsInt()` on it, passing the two previously generated numbers.

That's how it might look like.

```
public class Operations {
    public static final int RANGE = 100;
    public static final Random rand = new Random();
    
    public record Operation(String name, IntBinaryOperator operation) {}
    public static final List<Operation> operations =
            List.of(new Operation("add", Integer::sum), new Operation("sub", (i1, i2) -> i1 - i2),
                    new Operation("mult", (i1, i2) -> i1 * i2), new Operation("div", (i1, i2) -> i1 / i2));

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // you code (instansiate a scanner, enclose the code below with a while loop) 
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Operation oper = operations.get(rand.nextInt(operations.size()));
            int operand1 = rand.nextInt(RANGE);
            int operand2 = rand.nextInt(RANGE);
            System.out.println(operand1 + " " + oper.name() + " " + operand2); // exposing generated data to the user
            int userInput = sc.nextInt();                                      // reading user's input
            int result = oper.operation().applyAsInt(operand1,operand2);       // exposing the result
            System.out.println(result + "\n__________________");
        }
        // termination condition of the while loop
    }
}
```

That's an example of the output the user will see:

```
38 add 67
105 // user input
105
_____________________
97 sub 15
...
```

Answer (score 5):

No, you can't do that directly.  You will have to make a type that *represents* an operator.

The most common way to do this is with an enum:

```
enum Operator {
  PLUS {
    @Override int operate(int a, int b) {
      return a + b;
    }
  };

  abstract int operate(int a, int b);
}

Operator operator = Operator.PLUS;
int[] n = {1, 2};
System.out.println(operator.operate(n[0], n[1]));
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately java supports neither operator overloading nor infix notation, making it impossible to do so in source code.